# Console Application does NOT close immediately

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, ide, console, dev-c++

I decided to spend some time with `C++` again and that's why I downloaded the IDE named `Dev-C++` in the newest version this day.

From learning `C++` some years ago, I remembered that a console window would immediately  close after the `main()` function exits.

```
int main() {}
```

But the code line above doesn't let the console window only flash and disappear. Instead of this behaviour - which I actually expected - the console window appears and shows me the following message.

```
Process exited normally.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Was there a change I hadn't noticed in the last years? I can't remember the IDE to do these strange things and still less I can believe that the `GCC` compiler changed this way!

What's going on with my console application and how can I prevent the culprit from doing this?!

Update: To make things clear, this behaviour might be a so called feature. But I do not want to use this feature, because my application is used to set up a folder structure without showing any output. And, by the way, my operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: I know that Visual Studio does this when running the program from within the IDE. Have you tried calling it via shell?

Comment: And this console is on... mac? windows? linux? Eniac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is unrelated to the compiler or toolchain, but rather how the IDE is creating the consoles/terminals. I actually find it better to leave the windows open (in case there is any output that I want to verify).

Comment: Might be, but I need to disable it, as I mentioned. Is there a way? I couldn't find an option for that.

Comment: @sharethis: Why? My understanding is that this behavior is just when launching the application inside the IDE (have you tried running it externally?), so this behavior is only available during development.

Comment: You are right, the behavior is only available during development, and that is acceptable for me.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably just the IDE behaviour. I doubt the compiler inserts a pause at the end of the program. The IDE just lets you see the output before closing the window.

Comment: See my comment on David's answer.